# How to sort a nested list based on a column?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort the output of the list `entry` by the output:

```
itemTypes = ['phone','tower','laptop']
num = range(len(itemTypes))
for y in num:
    for row, entry in inventory.items():
        entry = [row] + entry
        for line in entry:
            if itemTypes[y] in line:
                print(entry)
```

This is the output I get from the code above is:

```
['3001265', 'Samsung', 'phone', '1200', '12/1/2023', '']
['1167234', 'Apple', 'phone', '534', '2/1/2021', '']
['1009453', 'Lenovo', 'tower', '599', '10/1/2020', '']
['9034210', 'Dell', 'tower', '345', '5/27/2020', '']
['2390112', 'Dell', 'laptop', '799', '7/2/2020', '']
['7346234', 'Lenovo', 'laptop', '239', '9/1/2020', 'damaged']
['2347800', 'Apple', 'laptop', '999', '7/3/2020', '']
```

When I try to add `entry = sorted(entry, key=lambda x: int(x[0]))` to the code to sort by the first element

```
if itemTypes[y] in line: 
    entry = sorted(entry, key=lambda x: int(x[0])) 
    print(entry)
```

I get this error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Project/test.py", line 29, in <lambda>
entry = sorted(entry, key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S'
```

So I tried the sorting function without the `int()` function and I get this error: `IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: `entry` is just one row, not all the rows.

Comment: You need to make a list of all the entries, and then sort that.

Comment: The line `entry = [row] + entry` will cause an error the first time an attempt is made to execute it because `entry` is undefined at the point. You also need to show a sample of what's in the `inventory` dictionary and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone mentioned, you first need to make a list of the entries and then sort

```
itemTypes = ['phone','tower','laptop']
entries = []
for item_id, row in inventory.items():
    if row[1] in itemTypes:
        entries.append([item_id] + row)
print(sorted(entries, key=lambda x: int(x[0])))
```

One-liner:

```
itemTypes = ['phone','tower','laptop']
sorted([[row] + entry for row, entry in inventory.items() if entry[1] in itemTypes], key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a list of the entries first and then sort that:

```
itemTypes = ['phone','tower','laptop']
num = range(len(itemTypes))
entry_list = []
for y in num:
    for row, entry in inventory.items():
        entry = [row] + entry
        for line in entry:
            if itemTypes[y] in line:
                entry_list.append(entry)
                print(entry)

sorted_entry = sorted(entry_list, key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

Something like this.

Comment: How would I put each of the sorted list in a csv

Comment: @BobbyTuPisto just use the `csv` module from standard Python.